# Spring always print logs at DEBUG level when running Maven

Tags: spring, maven, logging

I am using slf4j, logback for logging in my Spring application. I have configured to exclude common-logging and add the jcl-over-slf4j bridge.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

My logback.xml looks like the following:

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
<logger name="com.my" level="DEBUG" />
```

The problem is when running maven builds, classes from spring always prints in DEBUG level which pollutes the console with verbose information. This doesn't happen when running the app with Tomcat though.

Also, if I extend a class of Spring, e.g. HttpSessionRequestCache, logging statements from the Spring classes are executed, as if it get the level from the child class! This does happen when running with Tomcat.

How to make Maven honor the logback.xml configuration?

Comment: I guess you mean "how to make Maven honor the logback.xml configuration", since it seems that is your only issue. Which way you run your Maven builds, which goals?

Comment: Please check that logback.xml is included to your Maven build, likely it just does not package it by default.

Comment: Thanks Boris, I checked the target folder and see Maven does include logback.xml in there. @eis, there're 2 issues like I said, I think the second is not related to maven. For the 1st issue, I ran `install` goal which invokes my integration tests through maven-failsafe plugin.

Comment: @dnang I don't see any non-mavenrelated issue in your question. What is the second issue? In general, you should have one topic per question.

Comment: OK that makes sense, so I changed the wording, the problem with maven build logging is more important to me now.